# Is there a way to open file as File object from android's assets folder?

Tags: android, file, assets

I would like to get the filesize of a file located in the assets directory. I saw many examples like

```
 InputStream myInput = appContext.getAssets().open()
```

I know i can determine filesize by simple reading `InputStream` in cycle but I'm looking for a way to do this via `File object`.
 So i need a path to assets and thats the thing i can't determine... How to get that path?
 Also tried getting `AssetFileDescriptor` via `appContext.getAssets().openFd()` and `openNonAssetFd()` but no luck - got `FileNotFound` or probably compressed exceptions. 
 BTW those openFd methods are "pretty described" at developer.android.com.

---

I'd tried next code:

```
file = new File(new URI("file:///android_asset/db/call3.db"));
Log.i(APP_TAG, "File name: "+file.getName());
Log.i(APP_TAG, "File path: "+file.getPath());
Log.i(APP_TAG, "File length: "+file.length());
Log.i(APP_TAG, "File isFile: "+file.isFile());
Log.i(APP_TAG, "File exists: "+file.exists());
```

which outputs to log:

04-13 12:10:03.413: INFO(6259): File name: call3.db

04-13 12:10:03.432: INFO(6259): File path: /android_asset/db/call3.db

04-13 12:10:03.444: INFO(6259): File length: 0

04-13 12:10:03.444: INFO(6259): File isFile: false

04-13 12:10:03.444: INFO(6259): File exists: false

of course the size of file is not 0 it is 195 584  bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get that path?

There is no path. What you are seeking is not possible, sorry.

Comment: ok. and what about appContext.getAssets().openFd()/openNonAssetFd()? what is it for and why doesn't it work either?

Comment: Most heartbreaking answer ever, but true.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is any way to get a File object from an assets folder but to find out the length of a file in single line, you can use the following code.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
long size = afd.getLength();
```

Comment: openFd() will fail with the following error in most cases, since assets are generally compressed before being added to the APK: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed`. If you can rename your asset file to have one of the uncompressable extensions (like mp3) then the asset file will not be compressed when the APK is created and this method will actually work.

Comment: you can also add `android { aaptOptions { noCompress "zip_nocompression" } }` and force aapt not to compress assets with your custom extension